# Use MudBlazor MudDataGrid ServerData to load paged , retain selection on pagination and sorting

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Use MudBlazor MudDataGrid ServerData to load paged , retain selection on pagination and sorting

Mudblazor do not expose event on selectall/checked unchecked. On pagination if I click select all its not maintaining the states. This only happen with serverdata.